# How to filter erc721 mint transaction from pending pool?

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, go-ethereum

what i want to do is filter ERC721 mint transactions from mem pool

what i already known is :

1. subscrib pending:

   ```
   txch := make(chan common.Hash, 1000)

       _, err = gcli.SubscribePendingTransactions(context.Background(), txch)
   ```

   or

   ```
    provider.on("pending", (txHash) => { ....})
   ```
2. get transaction from txhash
3. use supportsInterface of ERC165 filter ERC721 and ERC1155
4. then what????

filter method name seems not the right way ,because in many mint case the method name is not "mint".
so i think obout the transfer event ,if it from 0x000000000,thats seems mint transaction,but how can i get the transfer event when the transaction in pending?

both golang and js solution will be fine